# Windows Vista login started appearing on startup, after starting sshd service via cygwin

Tags: authentication, cygwin, windows-vista, sshd

Today I've restarted my computer (running Windows Vista) and when it went up again, it showed a Windows log-in screen. This screen has never appeared before (for almost 4 years now. Windows is original, came with the laptop.

On the screen I had 2 options to enter with: PC-Name (let's call it Johnny) and "Privileged Server". Both of them are asking for password.
Now I don't think that I had ever set a password for my account, nor did it ever ask me to use one, in order to start Windows.
A few tries of my frequently used password, including some "easy" / default passwords such as 1234, admin, 1-9, and so on, were futile.

I am not able to enter my Windows at the moment.

What I suspect happened, is that Cygwin is somehow the cause for it.
Last week I tried to install Hadoop on my Windows, and I followed the Apache tutorial, which instructed to start sshd service on the computer (which is done with Cygwin). during the process of starting that service, there have been some steps that could have messed up the windows account. (setting RSA password / phraseless RSA thingie / whatever)
It also said in the middle, something about problems with the "accounts in the system".
I am sorry I can't be more informative about it, but these commands, among others, were used:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa 
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I can't find the exact tutorial(s) I've been working according to, but this one has some stuff I did: [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm)
the relevant steps are under the headline "Configuring SSH After Installing Cygwin", steps 1-4

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Look for cyg_server in your registry and get rid of it.  You will need it, however, if you're doing sshd with cygwin.